# Handling errors using angular $q.all

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, error-handling

I have an angular app that displays an editable grid to the user. The user is allowed to edit multiple rows in the grid, then save all those changes at once. When they do this, I am using `$q.all` to send out all the update calls to an API in parallel.

I want to be able to display an error to the user for each call that fails with some of the information about the object that wasn't saved correctly, but I can't figure out how to get that information out of the error handler.

```
var ops = []

_.each($scope.items, function (item) {
    if(item.Modified)
        ops.push(dataService.update(item.itemID, item.otherField))
})

$q.all(ops)
.then(function (repsonse) {
    //success
},
function (response) {
    //in here I want to output the itemID and otherField values for the item(s) that failed
})
```

Each item that is being sent out on the API call has a few properties on it (`itemID` and `otherField`). I want those values to be include in the error message to the user.

Is this possible using q.all or do I have to use another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$q.all` will trigger the error callback if *any* of the operations fail at any time, but in your case you just want to record which ones (if any) failed without triggering any additional error.  I would use return a promise from `.catch`:

```
ops.push(dataService.update(item.itemID, item.otherField))
.catch(function () {
    return {
        status: "failed",
        id: item.itemID
    };
});
```

Then in `$q.all`'s callback you can iterate over the responses and check for `.status == "failed"` and check those IDs.